# My UIToolBars is scrolling with the UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitoolbar

I've the following problem : I've a view containing a `UIScrollView` added with IB.
I also added a `UIToolBar` and added it to my view, but when I scroll it, the tool bar also moves. Any idea ?

Thanks for your advices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you have added `UIToolbar` as subview of `UIScrollView`.

You should just drag `UIToolbar` view from `UIScrollView` in IB and edit size of `UIScrollView`.

Comment: No I didn't, because I added my ToolBar programmatically and I did `[self.view addSubview:toolBar]`, not `[scrollView addSubview:toolBar]`

Comment: then your main view inherits UIScrollView or the contentrect of your UIScrollView encompasses the toolbar else it is not possible..(its not magic you see)

Comment: I agree with @roronoazorro . Does your main view inherit `UIScrollView`?

Comment: No it wasn't that, I've no idea why, but in IB when I added my ScrollView in my View this ScrollView was also linked to File's Owner view instead of the main view. Dunno why.. anyway, thanks a lot.